# is it possible to call upon the results of a previous ng-repeat to generate a new ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

i'm pretty new to angular and am generating a list based on an array.  However, if that array is empty, I don't want it to just show a blank screen, I want to show the items the logged in user is missing.  The first part of my ng-repeat works great, it generates a list of benefits someone has enrolled in.  However, in the second portion of my code, I want to generate all the benefits the user has not yet enrolled in, but it's obviously not working.  Is there a way to call upon the first ng-repeat and to generate the leftovers for the second ng-repeat?

```
<span class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in c.list track by $index" ng-if="item.sys_id">
  <h4><img class="icon" src="{{item.icon}}"> &nbsp;<strong>{{item.benefitType}}</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;<font size = 2><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green"/> Enrolled</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-edit pointer" ng-click="c.onWidget(item)"/></a></h4> 
  <p><strong>Plan Election:</strong> &nbsp;{{item.benefitProvider}} - {{item.planType}}</p>
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group">
  <span class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="thing in c.list2 track by $index" ng-if=***"?"***>
        <h4><img class="icon" src="{{thing.icon}}"> &nbsp;<strong>{{thing.benefit_name}}</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;<font size = 2><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" style="color:red"/>&nbsp;Not Enrolled</font></h4> 
  </span>
```

Comment: `ng-if="c.list.length === 0"`?

Comment: can u just put some logic in your controller that will fill up your c.list object with all the benefits you want, both enrolled in and not enrolled in? That seems like the better way to me. Your View layer should be void of most logic (i know there are some logic directives like ng-if), it should just present whatever data you pass to it. Have your controller configure your $scope according to your requirements.